# CSS Not Cascaded Properly to Label (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I have an FXML class built in SceneBuilder that's being loaded via FXMLLoader with a controller associated with it.  I have put a style class with a pseudo-class on the parent panel of the widget.  The ToggleButton is getting styled fine, but the two labels are not.

As a test, I tried directly giving one of the labels the CSS class.  The behavior was interesting; it picked up on the initial change, but did not have the text color updated when the pseudo class changed.

Below is the SCCEE that's cut out from production code.  All files are directly on the classpath.

CustomButton.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" styleClass="custom-button" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CustomButtonController">
   <children>
      <ToggleButton fx:id="selectionToggle" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="70.0" prefWidth="70.0" />
      <Label fx:id="dateLabel" alignment="TOP_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="5.0" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="60.0" styleClass="custom-button" text="Date" wrapText="true" />
      <Label fx:id="eventLabel" alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" contentDisplay="BOTTOM" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="40.0" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="60.0" text="Event" wrapText="true" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

CustomButtonController.java:

```
/**
 * Sample Skeleton for 'CustomButton.fxml' Controller Class
 */

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.css.PseudoClass;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;

public class CustomButtonController {
    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;
    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;
    @FXML // fx:id="dateLabel"
    private Label dateLabel; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML // fx:id="selectionToggle"
    private ToggleButton selectionToggle; // Value injected by FXMLLoader
    @FXML // fx:id="eventLabel"
    private Label eventLabel; // Value injected by FXMLLoader


    private Parent m_parent;


    @FXML // This method is called by the FXMLLoader when initialization is complete
    void initialize() {
        assert dateLabel != null : "fx:id=\"dateLabel\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'CustomButton.fxml'.";
        assert selectionToggle != null : "fx:id=\"selectionToggle\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'CustomButton.fxml'.";
        assert eventLabel != null : "fx:id=\"eventLabel\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'CustomButton.fxml'.";
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        m_parent = parent;

        selectionToggle.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                m_parent.pseudoClassStateChanged(PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("state2"), selectionToggle.isSelected());
                m_parent.applyCss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Main implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
        frame.setSize(800, 600);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/CustomButton.fxml"));
        Parent parent = loader.load();

        String cssString = getClass().getResource("/CustomButton.css").toExternalForm();
        parent.getStylesheets().add(cssString);

        CustomButtonController cont = loader.<CustomButtonController>getController();
        cont.setParent(parent);

        JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(parent));

        panel.add(jfxPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JFXPanel();
                Platform.runLater(new Main());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

CustomButton.css:

```
.custom-button:state2 { 
  -fx-base: cyan;
  -fx-text-fill: red;
  -fx-fill: yellow;
  -fx-stroke: purple;
}

.custom-button { 
  -fx-base: green;
  -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
```

Result (top is unselected, bottom is selected):

[image: Result]

Note that the ToggleButton obeys -fx-base, the date Label (which directly has the CSS class added to it) obeys -fx-text-fill for its initial color, but does not update on selection), and the event Label doesn't take anything from the CSS.

Comment: Is use of a pseudo-class necessary?  A Node can have as many style classes as you want, so why not use a selector like `.custom-button.state2` (period instead of colon) in your CSS instead?

Comment: @VGR Generally, pseudoclasses are a lot more convenient for this kind of functionality, as you don't have to worry about checking you don't add the same class multiple times.

Comment: @James_D I'm not sure I follow.  Whether a style class or pseudo-class is used, the code still has to remove it when returning the control to a normal state.  And in the worst case, adding a style class multiple times has no consequences (other than a small memory leak).  What am I missing?

Comment: @VGR If you might inadvertently add it multiple times, your code to remove it has to make sure it removes *all* copies. In cases where you don't control the invocation of the method that manages this (such as `updateItem(...)` in a cell implementation), you have to cover all possibilities. So you either need expensive (and ugly) `if (! getStyleClass().contains("my-style")) getStyleClass().add("my-style");` to add, or expensive (and ugly) `while (getStyleClass().contains("my-class")) getStyleClass().remove("my-style");`

Comment: @James_D Or, `getStyleClass().removeAll(Collections.singleton("my-style"))`, which doesn't seem all that bad to me.  I guess it's subjective;  to me, the use of PseudoClass seems more awkward.

Comment: Your version still has to iterate through the entire `getStyleClass()` list under the hood - so it is potentially very expensive. The pseudoclass effectively just sets a boolean. If you have more than two states, then I agree pseudoclasses are awkward. (Really, they should have implemented `styleClass` as an `ObservableSet`, not an `ObservableList`.) It's sort of OT though, exactly the same answer would apply if the OP had used style classes instead of pseudoclasses.

Comment: Just to weigh in on why I went the pseudo-class route, it wasn't a choice that was made out of pragmatism; it seemed to me that, conceptually, pseudo-classes are meant to represent the varying states of a given class, which is exactly what I was looking for.  I could've gone with different style classes and just updated the getStylesheets() list accordingly.  That might've prevented some of my confusion about how pseudo-classes work (though, it would be preventing it by pulling the wool over my eyes, so I'm glad to have learned what's happening).

Comment: I like to think that making this is just as much an opportunity to get a better understanding of JavaFX and CSS as it is producing the end result (though, my PM might disagree); any feedback like this as to things that could be handled better/differently is certainly welcome.

Comment: You would have seen exactly the same behavior with CSS classes as you saw with pseudoclasses.

Comment: I meant that I ended up learning more about the operation of pseudo-classes (namely, the fact that parents do not propagate their pseudo-class state to child classes).  I agree I probably would've ended up with the same behavior if I had attempted to implement via different style classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FXML applies the style class `custom-button` to the pane (the root of the fxml) and to the `dateLabel`. Thus your hierarchy from a CSS style class persepctive looks like

```
.custom-button
    .toggle-button.button.labeled
    .label.labeled.custom-button
    .label.labeled
```

From your listener, when the toggle button is selected, you set the `state2` pseudoclass on the root pane. So when selected, the hierarchy looks like

```
.custom-button:state2
    .toggle-button.button.labeled
    .label.labeled.custom-button
    .label.labeled
```

- Pseudoclass state is not inherited via the scene graph. So the `state2` pseudoclass state does not propagate to the child nodes.
- Values from looked-up colors [are propagated to the child
  nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor),
  so values of `-fx-base` (which is a looked-up color) are propagated
  from parent nodes to child nodes.
- Properties are generally not inherited. There are a couple of [specific exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#introinheritance), which do not include `-fx-text-fill`.

So the behavior you describe is expected given your code. The `dateLabel` gets a blue text fill, because it has the `custom-button` style class and `-fx-text-fill: blue;` is applied directly to that style class. It does not get `-fx-text-fill: red;` when the button is selected, because it does not have the pseudoclass `state2` set (only the root element has that pseudoclass). The values for `fx-base` are applied to the root node, and since it is a looked-up color those are propagated through the scene graph.

You can try something like

```
.custom-button {
    -fx-base: green ;
}
.custom-button:state2 {
    -fx-base: cyan ;
}
.custom-button .labeled {
    -fx-text-fill: blue ;
}
.custom-button:state2 .labeled {
    -fx-text-fill: red ;
}
```

to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Note that the style class is applied to the parent pane that contains the button and both labels, and that the pseudo class IS being propagated to the button (but not the event label, for either the pseudo class or the style class in general).  See the results of -fx-base.

Comment: I missed that `custom-button` was also declared on the root node. Updated answer accordingly. The value for `-fx-base` is propagated because it is a looked-up color, not because the pseudoclass state is propagated.

Comment: Okay I see what you're saying about the pseudo classes.  Thank you very much for the clarification, it's a big help.  If I'm understanding correctly, the behavior I'm noticing occurs because -fx-base is a looked-up color, but -fx-text-fill isn't (hence why the button base is getting updated, but the event label isn't)?  Why is that the case, and is there any way I can verify in the future if something is a looked-up color and something isn't?

Comment: I should clarify that I did read the looked-up color section in the link you provided to JavaFX colors, but it seems to me that they define looked-up colors as the equivalent of variables (IE: color = y vs. color = RED), than an attribute of properties (IE: something that applied to -fx-base but not other color properties).

Comment: There's no really definitive way to tell, other than reading through the modena.css source code. But [`textFill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#textFillProperty) has a corresponding property, so it is defined there rather than in the CSS; `base` doesn't.

Comment: Fair enough.  I didn't resolve it exactly as suggested, but the knowledge you shared did get me to the conclusion.  I'll accept your answer and follow with my own.  Thanks again for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I used "inherit" to ensure that my labels read -fx-text-fill from the custom parent class.  The resulting CSS is below:

CustomButton.css:

```
.custom-button:state2 { 
  -fx-base: white;
  -fx-text-fill: red;
}

.custom-button { 
  -fx-base: black;
  -fx-text-fill: cyan;
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: inherit;
}
```

It could also be done by defining a look-up color.

CustomButton.css:

```
.custom-button:state2 { 
  -fx-base: white;
  -labelColor: red;
}

.custom-button { 
  -fx-base: black;
  -labelColor: cyan;
}

.label {
    -fx-text-fill: -labelColor;
}
```